# carry values from Dynamic URL to Static URL in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dynamic-url

Dynamic URL  :
http://sample.com/articles.php?id=1&name=abc

Static URL  :
http://sample.com/article/

I need the id and name in the static URL hidden.

I tried with the below code in htaccess

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)&name=(.*)$`

`RewriteRule ^articles\.php$ /article/%1/%2? [R=301]`

`RewriteRule ^article/([^-]+)/([^-]+)$ /articles.php?article_id=$1&article_name=$2 [L]`

But in the code i have to use %1 and %2 to get the id and name.

Is there any way to get those values without `/%1/%2`

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: If you remove id and title from URL it how will you show correct content?

Comment: is there any way of hiding the values in URL...?

Comment: No values cannot be hidden in URL. Check this question's URL and imagine if you remove question id and slug

Comment: you can encode it using `base64_encode`.

Comment: instead of numeric values how can i get the alphabetical words in the url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `id` and `name` parameters without them being part in the URL:

1. Have the user send the values by POST, instead of GET (i.e., they select the values in a form and submit it).  Then the values are sent as part of the request body, not the URL.
2. Run the site on HTTPS, so no one can observe the request body as it's being sent.